# Javascript, update value by 2 events and concatenate

Tags: javascript, events, concatenation

A simple question.
I have 2 control change events.

I have the **first event** :

```
ctrlProducto_tipo.on  ('change', function(e){
  if (this.getValue()== 'Up'){
    var strProducto = 'U';}
  if (this.getValue()== 'Down'){
    var strProducto = 'D';}
  if (this.getValue()== 'Left'){
    var strProducto = 'L';}
  if (this.getValue()== 'Right'){
    var strProducto = 'R';}
  ctrlTest1.setValue(strProducto);
});
```

When i select 'Down' i have in my `text1.textfield` 'D'

In my second event to display in the **`Test2.textbox`**:

```
ctrlEspesor.on  ('keyup', function(e){
if (this.getValue()!== ''){
var strEspesor = ctrlEspesor.getValue();}
ctrlTest2.setValue(strEspesor);
```

When i put '4' i have '4'.

The 2 events works.
But now i try to concatenate `strProducto` and `strEspesor` to `ctrlTest3.textbox` (without display before in `ctrlTest1` & `ctrlTest2`).

But every time the user change one of both values i need `ctrlText3` update on fly.

I try **this**, without success.

```
var valueFinal = strProducto.concat(strEspesor);
ctrlTest3.setValue(valueFinal);
```

Example for `ctrlTest3` : 'D4'

A BIG HELP is welcome, thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand what you meant. 
Check this at [codepen](https://codepen.io/proabel-the-styleful/pen/mdbzPxO?editors=1010).

Javascript

```
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var txt1 = document.getElementById('text1');
var txt2 = document.getElementById('text2');
var txt3 = document.getElementById('text3');

select.addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
  txt1.value = e.target.value;
  txt3.value = txt1.value + txt2.value;
})

txt2.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
  txt3.value = txt1.value + txt2.value;
})
```

HTML part

```
  <select id="select">
    <option value="u">Up</option>
    <option value="d">Down</option>
    <option value="l">Left</option>
    <option value="r">Right</option>
  </select><br>
  <input type="text" id="text1"><br>
  <input type="text" id="text2"><br>
  <input type="text" id="text3">
```

Comment: That's works fine with your exemple. It's exactely what i want. But in my exemple i have problem with `select.addEventListener('change', (e)=>{` I use phprunner and it's different.

Answer (score 0):

With valueFinal, you cannot invoke strProducto and strEspesor within functions for a matter of scope, a solution would be to set the two variables in question globally.

```
var strProducto;  //globasl
ctrlProducto_tipo.on  ('change', function(e){
    if (this.getValue()== 'Up'){
        strProducto = 'U';}
    if (this.getValue()== 'Down'){
        strProducto = 'D';}
    if (this.getValue()== 'Left'){
        strProducto = 'L';}
    if (this.getValue()== 'Right'){
        strProducto = 'R';}
ctrlTest1.setValue(strProducto);
});

var strEspesor; //global
ctrlEspesor.on  ('keyup', function(e){
    if (this.getValue()!== ''){
        strEspesor = ctrlEspesor.getValue();}
ctrlTest2.setValue(strEspesor);


var valueFinal = strProducto.concat(strEspesor);
ctrlTest3.setValue(valueFinal);
```

Comment: Ok for the last 2 lines that don't work. I have nothing. Maybe a event is needed for the last 2 lines ?

Comment: I only reported the code as it was set, but surely an event is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The tips of Adel B, works. But under phprunner i thinks is different. I try to adapt Abel D code with that :

```
var select = Runner.getControl(pageid,'Producto_tipo');
var txt1 = Runner.getControl(pageid,'Producto_tipo');
var txt2 = Runner.getControl(pageid,'Espesor');
var txt3 = Runner.getControl(pageid,'EspesorNEW');

//select.addEventListener('change', (e)=>{ //<- with '=>' I have error
select.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    //txt1.value = e.target.value;
    txt1.value = e.target.value;
    //txt3.value = txt1.value + txt2.value;
    txt3.value = txt1.value + txt2.value;
})

//txt2.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{//<- with '=>' I have error
    txt2.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    //txt3.value = txt1.value + (txt2.value);
    txt3.value = txt1.value + (txt2.value);
})
```

But nothing.......